# Flask-Uploads : how to use with application factory

Tags: python, flask, flask-uploads

I am trying to implement Flask-Uploads in my project. However, I am having trouble because I am using an application factory function and cannot access the UploadSets from other files in the app!

**FILE: app/__init__.py**

```
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, IMAGES

def create_app(object_name):
    ...
    images = UploadSet('images', IMAGES)
    configure_uploads(app, images)
```

**FILE: app/controllers/editions.py**

```
from flask_uploads import UploadNotAllowed

# this is one of my route files, registered in a blueprint
editions = Blueprint('editions', __name__)

...
    # inside one of the routes
    poster = request.files.get('poster')
    try:
        filename = images.save(poster)
    except UploadNotAllowed:
        flash('The upload was not allowed.', category='warning')
    else:
        # add to db...
```

Of course this won't work because `images` is not defined. But how to I import it from the app?

I tried:

```
import app
app.images.save(...)

from flask import current_app
current_app.images.save(...)

from app import images
```

None works.
Any ideas???

PS: everything else in my app is working fine except this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out right after I posted here. It is simple, but can't find it explained nowhere:

On your controller/view file, where the routes are:

```
from flask_upload import UploadSet, IMAGES

my_upload_set = UploadSet('my_upload_set', IMAGES)

# (...) routes where you can use:
    image = request.files.get('image') # or whatever your form field name is
    try:
        filename = my_upload_set.save(image)
    except UploadNotAllowed:
        flash('The upload was not allowed.', category='warning')
    else:
        #  add to db
```

On your `app/__init__.py` file:

```
from app.controllers.my_view import my_upload_set
from flask_uploads import configure_uploads

def create_app(object):
    (...)
    configure_uploads(app, my_upload_set)
```

This should work like a charm! 
Any questions let me know...

Comment: I think you forgot to put **'import**' in `from app.controllers.my_view my_upload_set`

Comment: How may I use this pattern with flask-admin? I defined UploadSet in my view. Imported it in create_app, but I get "no destination for set dataupload" error at app start.